# Google Play Store SMS & CALL LOG permission removal

Tags: android

I removed the SMS and CALL_LOG permissions in accordance with new policy update and published the new build. But still, the warning on the dashboard is not removed. Can anyone please help me. Screenshot of permissions listed in the manifest is attached.[image: Permission screenshot from play store]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the SMS and CALL_LOGS permissions from the app's manifest file and then upload the latest build to store.On successful approval of your latest build, fill out this declaration form :-

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/viewform

The warning will be removed from playstore